# WPF C# Textbox autosave function

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello everyone just a quick question, i'm trying to implement an autosave function onto a text box for a password remembering software i'm making for myself. I came across answers saying to `Binding.UpadateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`, for `TextBox.Text`. And i have tried doing so but i end up with tons of errors (new to C# and VS), if that is the only way to do this how could i do so with this code (im using mahapps metro for good looks):

`

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="469" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="692">

        <TabItem Header="Logins">
            <Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352"/>                  
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Cards">
            <Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
          <TabItem Header="Renewals">
            <Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352"/>
            </Grid>

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your TextBox data by using Default Settings of your application.

On Click event of some control or TextChanged event of the TextBox you can save the TextBox data:

```
YourAppID.Properties.Settings.Default.DataToSave = TextBox.Text;
```

On WindowLoaded event or some control event you can get the data you've saved to TextBox:

```
TextBox.Text = YourAppID.Properties.Settings.Default.DataToSave;
```

Important moment in this, that you preliminarily must add the "DataToSave" field to your project properties.

Good luck

Comment: Be aware that WPF settings by default save to a location specific to the application version. If you use WPF settings, be prepared to leave your AssemblyVersion number the same all the time, or implement your own `SettingsProvider` that saves the file to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you need to consider.

First, you need a good way of encrypting the passwords. You don't want to save the passwords as plain text because then anyone who has access to the file can read all of your passwords. (If this is a personal app then maybe only you have access to the file, but since you are making an app instead of using a plain text file, I assume your situation is more complicated.)

C# comes with a number of encryption libraries that you can use, such as [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx). You should read up a lot on encryption and IVs so you understand how to implement it in a secure manner. Basically, you need to generate a key that you will use to encrypt/decrypt the file. How you store this key can be complicated, depending on how secure you want to be. You can hard-code the key into your app, but be aware that someone could potentially decompile your app and get the key. Also, every time you encrypt a password, you should generate an IV and prepend the IV at the beginning of the encrypted password bytes. Then you can use the IV to decrypt the password later.

For examples of encryption and decryption, see the [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) page. Note that, unlike the example, you don't want to call `myRijndael.GenerateKey();` every time you encrypt something - instead you should set `myRijndael.Key` equal to whatever your pre-generated key is.

Next, you need to decide where to store the file that saves the password. You can store it in the same directory as the application, but if your application is in Program Files, then you might run into access rights issues since your program will need to run as administrator to write to Program Files. You probably want to save to somewhere like ApplicationData:

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    "MyApp",
    "pw.txt");
// filePath = C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\pw.txt (for Windows Vista and later)
// You can also use Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData if you want the file to be accessible to all user accounts on the machine.
```

Also, on a side note, I think `Binding.UpadateSourceTrigger` is irrelevant for this. By default for `TextBox.Text`, the binding will update when the text box loses focus. If you change it to `PropertyChanged`, the binding will update for every character in the text box. In your case, I think the default behaviour is fine. If you are using [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), just make sure your auto-save code is in the Passowrd setter in you ViewModel and you're golden.

Comment: Also, if you need clarification for anything, let me know. I went over things at a pretty high level so some of it might be unclear.

Comment: You should never encrypt a password, a hash with a salt is preferred if you really must store passwords.

Comment: @Unflux - I assume he needs to be able to decrypt the password at some point, in which case a hash will not work.

Comment: You should not be able to decrypt a password for security reasons. I recommend you research password salting and hashing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value in the `TextBox` to automatically update your `DependencyProperty` backing source as you type, then you were on the right track with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.  The default `UpdateSourceTrigger` for the `Text` Property of a `TextBox` is `LostFocus`.

I've thrown together a quick example for you using Code-Behind for you to play with.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="469" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="692">
            <TabItem Header="Logins">
                <Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Width="352" Text="{Binding LoginsTextBoxText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Cards">
                <Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Width="352" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Renewals">
                <Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Width="352" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string loginsTextBoxText;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string LoginsTextBoxText
        {
            get { return this.loginsTextBoxText; }
            set
            {
                this.loginsTextBoxText = value; // Put a breakpoint here and type in the logins textbox
                this.OnPropertyChanged(this.LoginsTextBoxText);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On a related note but not actually part of the question, aj_r has valid point regarding password management.  If this is just an app for you to play with and get to grips with things then no biggie, if however you intend to actually use this app at some point then you will want to research password management and replace the `TextBox` controls with `PasswordBox` controls.

Comment: Thanks, and yes im using this to just play around with and learn different things you can do with it.